# Autocomplete django in visual studio code

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

hello everyone I am having a problem the visual studio code autocomplete for django does not work for me, because for python it does it without problems but when working with django the framework options do not work, that is when I work with views based on classes does not generate the autocomplete, such as template_name, form_class, etc ..., likewise with the models it does not generate the help of max_length, and those other things of the framework, I have selected the interpreter but it does not work for me and also python: build workspace symbols and nothing. in advance I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6):

You can install and activate python & Microsoft AI extension in visual studio code.

[image]

Comment: If you are working purely on python try avoid other extension like Javascript syntax etc

Comment: seems to be a bug

Answer (score 5):

install some of the plugins for local and global

Global in vscode extensions:

1. Python (Microsoft)
2. Djaneiro
3. code spell checker

local:

```
pip install —dev autopep8 pep8 pylint pylint_django
```

Press CTRL+SHIFT+P(CMD+SHIFT+P for MacOS) -> ">select interpreter" -> select your virtual envirnoment
https://i.ibb.co/TTfkHRF/select-vir.gif

open `vscode/setting.json` file and past the beneath config code:

```json
{
  ....
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugin=pylint_django"
  ]
}
```